# Beamer presentation to pure frames

Tags: beamer

I need to format a presentation in beamer to a mode where only the frames are visible (ergo no header no footer). Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you currently using any theme? If you are, try disabling it (comment the code used to pick the theme).

Here, not picking any theme results in a clean and simple format (well, except for these PDF buttons on the bottom right corner, but I guess there's some way to disable that, too).

Here goes some example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Example of simple layout slideshow with \LaTeX{} Beamer}
\author{njsg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{Large}
      \textbf{Slideshow}
    \end{Large}

    \vfill

    This

  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A frame title}

  And that.
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: To disable the navigation symbols, use `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}`